# Unable do debug a .so library that makes my shell segfault

Tags: c, unix, segmentation-fault, malloc, mmap

I am trying to make **malloc**, **free** and **realloc** functions in C (using mmap).

I am using following commands line to include them in my shell (I am using sh) :

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
export DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE=1
export DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES="./malloc.so:./free.so:./realloc.so"
```

Here is some of my malloc code :

```
#include "../incs/malloc.h"

void        *malloc(size_t size)
{
    write(2, "\nMALLOC", 7);
    t_block     *res;

    write(2, "0", 1);

    res = NULL;

    if (!(glob))
    {
        write(2, "1", 1);
        // First call of malloc, need to init glob variable
        glob = init_glob();
    }
    write(2, "2", 1);
    res = get_block(size);
    write(2, "3", 1);

    if (!res)
    return (NULL);

    write(2, "4", 1);

    return (res->memory);
}
```

I have a debug write too at the start of my init_glob() function.

When I execute the previous command lines in my shell, and run a random command (ls, for example), here is what I get :

```
MALLOC01
MALLOC01
MALLOC01
MALLOC01
MALLOC01
MALLOC01
MALLOC01
MALLOC01
MALLOC01
MALLOC01
MALLOC01
MALLOC01
MALLOC01
MALLOC01
MALLOC01Segmentation fault: 11
```

I don't really understand why it is not working, and how do debug this.

It should just write "MALLOC01" once, ten go to my init_glob function.
Why is this looping like this ?
How can i see WHERE it is crashing in ls command ?

Thanks in advance.

===== EDIT =====

Here is my init_glob() function :

```
#include "../incs/malloc.h"

/*
**  This function returns a t_glob.
**  It shall init the global variable of type t_glob, on the first time
**  malloc is called in a process.
*/
t_glob      *init_glob(void)
{
    write(2, "a", 1);
    t_glob      *res;

    res = NULL;

    write(2, "b", 1);
    res = (t_glob *)allocate_memory(sizeof(t_glob));

    write(2, "c", 1);

    res->tiny = NULL;
    res->small = NULL;
    res->large = NULL;
    write(2, "d", 1);

    return (res);
}
```

And my allocate_memory() function (but it seems that the program is not even going there) :

```
void        *allocate_memory(size_t size)
{
    void        *res;

    res = NULL;

    res = mmap(0, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);

    return (res);
}
```

My t_glob struct is prototyped like this :

```
typedef struct                  s_glob
{
    t_page                      *tiny;
    t_page                      *small;
    t_page                      *large;
    // size_t                   sizeof_block; // Avoid repeat of sizeof() call
    // size_t                   sizeof_page;
    // size_t                   getpagesize_result;
}                               t_glob;
```

Comment: Show us your `init_glob` function.

Comment: It looks like malloc() is called recursively from init_glob(). Are you sure you're using write() in init_glob() and not printf() or other stdio function? Or is write() itself some kind of wrapper instead of the write(2) system call?

Comment: Yes, I am sure that I am using write, as printf have some strange behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't really understand why it is not working, and how do debug this.

The usual way to debug this is to let the program dump `core` (`ulimit -c unlimited`), and then *look* with the debugger where the infinite recursion happens.

If I were to guess, I would guess that when the dynamic loader tries to resolve the call from `malloc` to `init_glob`, this dynamic symbol resolution *itself* needs dynamic memory and calls `malloc`.

You would get a better answer (less guessing) if you provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including build instructions.